# What happens if you remove bijectivity from the definition of a homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

I suppose the question is in the title. My immediate thought would be to extend to set-valued functions, and that doesn't seem like a huge problem, at least not obviously. For example, you could "blow up" (abuse of terminology) a point into an open set of a separate topology by mapping that point onto an interval.

Does this idea make sense, and if so, where can I find references to it, if any?

EDIT: Noah's comment has given some axioms for some weak relations satisfying these properties:

Given topological spaces $(X,\tau)$, $(Y,\sigma)$, we say a relation $R \subseteq X\times Y$ is *almost homeomorphic* if it satisfies the following axioms:

$(i)$ For each $U \in \tau$ we have $R(U)\in \sigma$.

$(ii)$ For each $V \in \sigma$, we have $R^{-1}(V)\in \tau$.

$(iii)$ For each $x \in X$, there is at least one $y \in Y$  such that $xRy$ is true.

Comment: @aldodecristo In general you do get not local homeomorphisms. Consider any map $\mathbb R \to \{*\}$.

Comment: Do you mean if we assume that maps are continuous and open?

Comment: "an embedding is a homeomorphism onto its image", https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedding#General_topology

Comment: Per your comment about blowing up points, it sounds like you're interested in the following: given topological spaces $(X,\tau),(Y,\sigma)$, a relation $R\subseteq X\times Y$ such that $(i)$ for each $U\in\tau$ we have $R(U)\in\sigma$, $(ii)$ for each $V\in\sigma$ we have $R^{-1}(U)\in\tau$, and $(iii)$ for each $x\in X$ there is at least one $y\in Y$ with $xRy$. So we drop a priori injectiveness, surjectiveness, and single-valuedness. Does that seem right?

Comment: Any map $f:(X,\tau_X)\rightarrow(Y,\tau_Y)$ induces a function $f^*:\tau_Y\rightarrow \tau_X$, $U\mapsto f^{-1}(U)$. I have seen the definition that $f$ is a *quasihomeomorphism* if $f^*$ is bijective. Obviously every homeomorphism is a quasihomeomorphism, but there are quasihomeomorphisms which are not bijective. If $X$ is any space and $X_0$ the quotient $T_0$ space formed by identifying $x\sim y$ iff $\overline{\{x\}}=\overline{\{y\}}$, then $X\rightarrow X_0$ is a surjective quasihomeomorphism which is bijective iff $X$ is $T_0$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes, that's the sort of definition I have in mind. I'll add it to the question, while making sure that alternative definitions and additional axioms are encouraged. I suppose now my question becomes "what interesting relations can we construct with properties at least this strong, but not quite as strong as a homeomorphism?"

Comment: Each open continuous map $f$ (and its inverse, if $f$ is surjective) will have this property. [Related](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/179123/continuous-relations).